# How to grep through files which match a regex

Tags: grep

I wish to search for keyword "test", in all files which are of type "*.spec.in" in the current directory recursively 
This doesn't work:

```
grep -rn "test" ./*.spec.in
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you think about what this does, this can't work. The -r flag means grep will expect a directory as it's file source, but your glob will match files (or nothing). This is a mismatch.

You can do this a few ways.

The "textbook" way, usable on any UNIX (any shell really) is to separate responsibility. Use `find` to do the recursion, and separately do grep. Lets find all the files that match, and hand those to grep

```
find . -type f -name '*.spec.in' | xargs grep -n "test"
```

find, starting from here, files, with name matching '*.spec.in', passing that stream off to xargs, which will turn the stream into command line args for your grep.

If you have no spaces in filenames, this is fine. But if you do, or if you use this to make changes on disk, you probably want this a bit tighter. There are hacks where you can mess with filenames to harm important files on disk, so you want to be very careful for filename hacks. For security, or spaces in names, you can tell find and xargs to communicate more tightly. See `-print0`, `-0` below.

```
find . -type f -name '*.spec.in' -print0 | xargs  -0 something_destructive_like_rm
```

On newer shells, such as zsh or newer versions of bash you can use recursive globs, which use a special ** syntax. They'll recursively match a file pattern.

```
shopt -s globstar # needed for bash, not for zsh
grep "test" ./**/*.spec.in
```